# access variables from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I've just switched from PHP to rails and I'm trying to figure out how to get my menu_price controller to access a variable from my categories controller.

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
     @categories = Category.all
  end
```

I thought of global variables but rad that this was not a safe approach. I also read that ruby does not support multiple inheritance which was going to be my second approach.

Here's my menu controller (I only added a portion of it because the rest of the code is not relevant.)

```
class MenuPricesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_menu_price, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @menu_prices = MenuPrice.all
  end
```

I'm sure this is very simple but I've been looking for the past hour or so for an answer. I read about the concern folder but I'm not sure how to approach that, I haven't gotten that far in my book.

Comment: this post have a good answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591031/accessing-one-controller-variable-in-another-controller-in-rails/20591384#20591384

Comment: Why would you need to access variables from another controller? If you need `Category` in `MenuPricesController` just instantiate it there as @RailsOuter demonstrated in his answer.

Though I must admit this is a code smell. I have a gut feeling that `Category` and `MenuPrice` are supposed to have an association between them. If that were the case, you'd be able to only fetch categories and get their menu prices as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `MenuPricesController` you can create a new `Category` instance and use it like this :

```
class MenuPricesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_menu_price, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


 def index
    @menu_prices = MenuPrice.all
    @categories = Category.all
    # do something
  end
```

Comment: thanks I have no idea why it didn't work the first time I tried this

Answer (score 1):

Category.all isn't defined in your CategoriesController class, it's in the Category class (which I assume is an ActiveModel model...) You can (and should) create your instance variable within your controller action.